# How can I have this specific line in one line and not two!

Tags: moderncv

I would like to have the element surrounded by a red rectangle in one line and not to:
Maybe there is something to force him to be shown in one line or maybe I can reduce the the margin left for this specific element but I don't know how to do it
[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Mehmet} % Your first name
\familyname{DEMIR} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
%\title{Étudiant en réseaux et télécommunications}
\address{50, rue de la Paix}{77270 Villeparisis}
\phone{06 52 42 28 65}
\email{demir.mehmet90@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{23 ans}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{Permis B / Véhiculé}
\photo[100pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
\quote{Obtenir un contrat d'apprentissage d'une durée de trois ans en cycle ingénieur}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
\vspace*{-1.5cm}

\section{Formations}
\cventry{2013 -- 2014}{Formation d'Ingénieurs}{Institut Galilée}{}{}{Spécialité Télécommunications et Réseaux}
\cventry{2010 -- 2013}{Diplôme Universitaire de Technologie}{I.U.T de Villetaneuse (Paris XIII)}{}{}{Spécialité Télécommunications et Réseaux}
\cventry{2010}{Baccalauréat Scientifique}{Lycée Gérard de Nerval (Noisiel, 77186)}{}{}{Spécialité Physique-Chimie}

\section{Compétences}
\cvitem{Langages}{Java, HTML5/CSS3, Javascript, C/C++, PHP, SQL, Script Shell, XML}
\cvitem{Environnements}{Windows, Linux, Android}
\cvitem{Réseaux}{Mise en places des architectures LAN / WLAN}
\cvitem{}{Principe d'interconnexion de réseaux TCP/ IP}
\cvitem{}{Paramétrage de routeurs CISCO}
\cvitem{}{Mise en place d'outils réseaux sur un serveur Linux : DHCP, VPN, firewall et proxy}
\cvitem{}{Réseaux locaux, Ethernet}
\cvitem{Télécoms}{Configuration PABX, VoIP}
\cvitem{}{Fibre optique}
\cvitemwithcomment{Langues}{Anglais}{Bon niveau (\textbf{950} au dernier \textbf{TOEIC})}
\cvitemwithcomment{}{Espagnol}{Débutant}
\cvitemwithcomment{}{Turc}{Bilingue}
\cvitem{Logiciels}{Microsoft Office, Open Office}

\section{Expériences professionnelles}

\cventry{Mars 2012\\\`a  Aujourd'hui}{Auto-entrepreneur}{}{}{}{Gestion de Oues Peinture, entreprise spécialisée dans la peinture et travaux de rénovation.\newline{}}

\cventry{Avril 2013\\\`a Juin 2013}{Stage de fin d'études}{University of Bergen}{Norv\`ege}{}{Développement d'une application mobile Android pour contr\^oler une prise de courant GSM.\newline{}}

\cventry{2006 - 2012}{Travailleur saisonnier}{SBR Décoration}{entreprise de B.T.P}{}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Préparation de commandes, factures et devis,
\item Elaboration de l'emploi du temps des salariés,
\item Gestion des courriers de l'Assurance Retraite et de l'URSSAF.\newline{}
\end{itemize}}

\section{Centres d'intérêt}
\cvitem{Intérêts}{Association << Entraide Scolaire Amicale >>}
\cvitem{Sport}{Football en salle, musculation}
\cvitem{Cinéma}{Films et séries anglophones en version originale}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or less clean but maybe simpler than patching: `\quote{\makebox[0pt]{Obtenir un contrat d'apprentissage d'une durée de trois ans en cycle ingénieur}}`.

Comment: @PaulGessler it worked, thank you very much :)